# Calculate string size without render

Tags: javascript, string, d3.js

I'm using d3.js, and to calculate string size, first I append the string to the DOM and call `textContainer.node().getBBox()` to get its width and height.

But there is possible to get the string size without rendering string using d3.js or some other js library ?

Comment: Rendering of the DOM will happen only *after* your current code on the call stack is done. If you add the text to the DOM, get the bounding box and remove it right afterwards, it will never get rendered.

Comment: It's what I actually do. But I have a lot of text to calculate, it's not really optimised. It took 20 second to render a page :/

Comment: Since it won't get rendered... what is your question then?

Comment: I just want to get string's size. But to do that, I have to render the string first, get size and then remove this string. It took a lot of time when I do that. My question is: it's possible to get a string's size without doing these steps ?

Comment: No, you won't need to actually render the string to get its dimensions. Just adding, getting the size and removing will do. Remember, that manipulating the DOM and rendering are different things. Rendering is not necessary for this. Maybe, there are other problems with your code. Could you set up demo, maybe a scaled down one to just show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is [ctx.measureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) function exactly for that, note, that you need to specify font, size etc (as in CSS) to get correct output, and the result may be sub pixel.

Comment: I just read the documentation. It seems this function work only on <canvas> tag right ? Have you a function for <svg> ?

Comment: No, there ain't one, however, you can create a canvas via javascript and NOT attach it to document, therefor not render it. Sorry but there ain't no way to test for string width without being rendered other than canvas.